# How could I comunicate with the terminal using an external device connected through usb port?

Tags: c++, terminal, arduino, usb, uart

I want to program an arduino in such a way so that when I connect the arduino to any computer via usb port, the arduino will communicate with the computer's terminal and execute hardcoded commands. How could I make this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically just 2 options for you:

1. You have to install additional software/driver on the computer first that executes the commands and communicate with your arduino via normal serial commands.
2. Your arduino has to emulate something that is allready allowed to send the computer commands like the keyboard or mouse for example. But this won't work with just any computer as you can only simulate a keyboard and have to use key shortcuts/text specific for the OS running on that computer.

You can search for USB Rubber Ducky to see how that's done as they do exactly what you might want to do.